# Publishing Users information but without "secret" fields

Tags: meteor, publish

I am publishing multi-user information (using Meteor.users collection) for the purpose of naming posts creators and have their names and other small details associated with those posts, but I do NOT want to publish the complete documents for each user as they have "secret" login information.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Meteor.publish("serverforumthread", function(thread){
    check(thread, String);

    var replies = forumReplies.find({thread: thread});
    var users = {};
    replies.map(function(r){
        users[r.owner] = r.owner;
    });
    var userids = _.map(users, function(value, key){ return value; });   
    var projectedFields = {_id:1, username:1, forumStats: 1, services: 0};    
    var usrs = Meteor.users.find({_id:{$in: userids}}, projectedFields);
    var anyUpdateToUsers = false;
    usrs.map(function(owner){
        var changed = false;
        if(!owner.username){
            owner.username = owner.emails[0].address.split("@")[0]; 
            changed = true;
        }
        //owner.forumStats = undefined;
        if(!owner.forumStats){
            owner.forumStats = {};
            owner.forumStats.postCount = 0;
            owner.forumStats.postLikes = 0;
            owner.forumStats.title = "the newbie";
            owner.forumStats.tag = "newbie";
            owner.forumStats.img = "http://placehold.it/122x122";
            changed = true;
        }
        if(changed){
            anyUpdateToUsers = true;
            Meteor.users.update({_id: owner._id}, {$set:{ forumStats:owner.forumStats }});
        }
    });  
    if(anyUpdateToUsers) // refresh it
         usrs = Meteor.users.find({_id:{$in: userids}}, projectedFields);

    usrs.map(function(owner){
        console.log(owner);
    });
    return [replies, usrs];
});
```

As you can see, I am only interested in publishing relies (posts) for a thread and their associated users username and small forumStats, I want to keep the "services" key secret, as it contains details that should not be published.

A sample output of the "console.log":

```
{ _id: 'hoRYFbRkXXbHYm8Ty',
   createdAt: Tue Jun 03 2014 16:25:42 GMT+0100 (WEST),
   emails: [ { address: 'somemail@gmail.com', verified: false } ],
  forumStats: 
    { postCount: 85,
      postLikes: 5,
      title: 'the newbie',
      tag: 'newbie',
      img: 'http://placehold.it/122x122' },
   services: 
    { password: { srp: [Object] },
      resume: { loginTokens: [Object] } } }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the examples in the [field specifiers](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers) section of the docs, and give this a try:

```js
var projectedFields = {fields: {username:1, forumStats: 1}};
```

You'll get `_id` for free, and it will only include the other fields that you specify. Note that you can't mix inclusion and exclusion options, meaning you can't have both 0's and 1's.

If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll look more carefully.

Comment: It did not seem to work. However, now that I think about it, I am only reading comments from my own "user" since there is no one else on the system right now, so, I might be getting the "extra" fields from just being logged in.

Edit: The "extra" services field disapears if I refresh and dont navigate to the post page (not executing the subscribe), so, I am pretty sure that field is being published.

Comment: Yeah you automatically get other fields like your profile for your own user. Keep in mind that fields for the same `_id` from multiple publishers will merge together on the client. I'd recommend testing locally with additional users to make sure you only see the correct fields for other users.